# Magento: AddAttributeToSort not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have a piece of code that uses the getCollection() method to pull out some records:

```
$banner = Mage::getModel('banner/banner')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', '1')
            ->addFieldToFilter('banner_group', 'homepage_banner');
```

This works fine but I want to sort the results by their 'order' field (numeric).

So I motified the code to look like this:

```
$banner = Mage::getModel('banner/banner')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSort('order', 'ASC')
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', '1')
            ->addFieldToFilter('banner_group', 'homepage_banner');
```

But now it just crashes and I get a blank page.

Anyone any idea what is happening here? Is it because I'm doing addAttribute and not addField like I am to filter?

Thanks,

Billy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute only applies to EAV types, try using `addOrder` instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can use setOrder('attribute',$value);
to reset